# Is there a Powershell equivalent to nscurl ats-diagnostics?

Tags: windows, powershell, mac-osx, curl

I know that `nscurl` is coming on MacOS since El Captain, but I am wondering if there is a way to get similar results using PowerShell.

This [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/820698/436558) shows how to get the certificate, but it isn't equivalent to running:

```
nscurl --ats-diagnostics https://google.com:443
```

on a macOS. Is there anything like that on the Windows side?

Comment: It might help to explain what 'nscurl ats-diagnostics' actually does so people unfamiliar with that tool don't have to go look it up.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about a PowerShell equivalent, but the following could help nevertheless, either to do the same thing manually or for someone to build the appropriate PowerShell script.

From the name and what I read, `nscurl` is a wrapper around `curl` that just makes sure that the server conforms to Apple requirements which are TLS 1.2 and PFS in summary

`curl --verbose` already gives you things like `SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256` so you need to display that properly and then test values against Apple full specification.

Apple full requirements (https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf) are in fact:

- *cipher selection to include only suites 
  that provide forward secrecy, specifically ECDHE_ECDSA_AES and 
  ECDHE_RSA_AES in GCM or CBC mode* and RSA_AES could be added if forward secrecy is disabled on some domain
- *Servers must support TLS v1.2 and forward secrecy*
- *certificates must be valid and signed using SHA-256 or better with a minimum 2048-bit RSA key or 256-bit elliptic curve key*

So all of this is basically given by `curl --verbose` or even `openssl s_client`.

In fact, reading https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14816 you discover there is another tool provided called `TLSTool` that can help, and based on its API it is clearly a wrapper around `openssl`.