# How to ssl a google compute engine server?

Tags: cloud, google, gcloud

I have a docker image that looks like

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update; \
  apt-get install -y libsnappy-dev software-properties-common; \
  add-apt-repository universe ldconfig; \
  add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot \
  apt-get update


WORKDIR /

COPY . /

EXPOSE 80
CMD  chmod 777 build;
 ./build
```

with build looking like

```
#!bin/bash
./database & (sleep 3s && ./server);
```

And I have this up and running on my compute engine instance,
I now need to make sure that my VM is https. I've tried running certbot  through ssh, But as it is a read only system, and I don't quite understand How am I am to certify the website.

Comment: https://scmquest.com/nginx-docker-container-with-https-protocol/

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-group-ssl

Answer (score 0):

To use SSL on my virtual machine. I used https://letsencrypt.org/. They make it very easy. Also you can use openssl to view your certificate. `echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -servername gnupg.org -connect gnupg.org:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -inform pem -noout -text` [Displaying a remote SSL certificate details using CLI tools](https://serverfault.com/questions/661978/displaying-a-remote-ssl-certificate-details-using-cli-tools) I am not familiar with using the google compute engine in particular, but from my understanding you should be able to treat it as a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

For SSL follow below steps

1. domain name  should associated with your server’s public IP address.
2. `openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -serverkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -out server.crt`
3. Create a Nginx default.conf
4. create a Dockerfile
   Follow  [link](https://scmquest.com/nginx-docker-container-with-https-protocol/)

Some more references [Enabling HTTPS with Let's Encrypt on Docker](https://medium.com/bros/enabling-https-with-lets-encrypt-over-docker-9cad06bdb82b)  and [container-instances-container-group-ssl](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-group-ssl)