# nmap - get ssl expiration from fqdn

Tags: nmap

lets say i have the following url:

> [www.domain.com:4567/blabla/index.html](http://www.domain.com:4567/blabla/index.html)

I'm trying to get its' ssl expiration date.

There's this:

```
nmap --script=ssl-cert.nse -p 9194 www.domain.com
```

but it doesnt quite work.
I'm unable to find the right argument in nmap.

Edit: I  could go for Openssl but I need a Windows based solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying a remote SSL certificate details using CLI tools](https://serverfault.com/questions/661978/displaying-a-remote-ssl-certificate-details-using-cli-tools)

Comment: Nope. That's not nmap.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why is it so important to use `nmap`, and no other tools? I mean, the command you wrote does print the expiration date, all you need to grep it out.

Comment: uhm, yes, there are answers to that question that use nmap. But nmap is generally not the tool of choice for this, usually one just uses openssl.

Comment: `doesnt quite work`. Would help if you provided the output of the command.

Comment: I actually could go for Openssl but I need a Windows based solution and this is a bash-centric solution. I wanted NMAP because I already had a Powershell-NMAP script that did checked websites for expiring ssls but once I got something with different ports and paths it just errored out on bad syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The URL you showed is for port 4567. Therefore, you need to use that port in your Nmap scan: `nmap -p4567 --script ssl-cert www.domain.com`

Also, if the port you're scanning is not one of the typically-expected ports for SSL/TLS, then the script might not run. You can force it to run by adding `+` to the script name (not recommended for scans of multiple ports): `nmap -p4567 --script +ssl-cert www.domain.com`. Newer versions of Nmap will usually not need this because they will just try a probe to check if they can open a SSL connection anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to us is:

```
nmap -sV -p 443 --script ssl-cert example.com
```

You need to include `-sV` option for service discovery.